# Sas workspace on SaS EG

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

We have default SAS workspace of x TB. We also have alternate 10X TB workspace on same server at different folder location.

Can anyone please help me with syntax that can be used in SAS EG to point to the alternate workspace instead of default one?

Comment: Hey Rajiv, it depends on your environment and what you have boughts from SAS. When you say Workspace location, do you mean you have defined a new workspace server?

Comment: Thanks  Vasilij. We ahve server Sas hosted on unix. The another workspace is folder on the same server.

Comment: What do you mean by "workspace" in your question?

Comment: Its Workspace as per the SaS definition.

Comment: Definition: SAS Workspace Servers interact with SAS by creating a server process for each client connection. The workspace server process is owned by the client user who made the server request. Each workspace server process enables client programs to access SAS libraries, perform tasks by using the SAS language, and retrieve the results.

Comment: As you can see, the oficual definition has nothing to do with folders. Workspace server might have library definitions that might refer to, but not always to a folder on OS. Workspace server might have work and utility memory allocation that should be configured for separate file systems, but might be configured to refer to a folder. I am not sure what is your question. The uses can't access a workspace server or a folder on the OS? By the way, SAS is the analytical software, SaS is referring to " Software as Service"

Comment: Question is unclear... Do you mean changing working directory?? If so, look into X or CALL SYSTEM commands which can send "cd dirX" directly to the OS. For more info: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/61879/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000303551.htm

Answer (score 3):

The SAS work directory can be changed for individuals by creating a $HOME/sasv9.cfg file and placing one line in it:

-WORK {full path to the SAS work directory}

Answer (score 1):

if you are running in unix, you can change the work directory in the execution. nohup sas -work /myworkdirectory mypgm.sas &

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the SAS work library, which is the location where SAS lets you store temporary data sets?

If so, then it depends.  Are you using EG to in a client/server setup?  In that setup you will have to get your SAS Admin to make changes on the server or in the SAS Metadata to point the work library for all Workspace Servers that start to use the other location that has more available space.

Answer (score 0):

Would you not define SAS libraries out of these workspaces?

i.e. libname mydata '/folders/myfolders/'

This will then assign each library to your active SAS session.

Use this as precode to any manipulation your doing.

If you have Management Console, or Using PROC METADATA you can create permanent libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned workspace, so I assume you need to control the WORK library.

Use the SAS system option

options    work=library-specification

In the SAS documentation it states: specifies the libref or physical name of the storage space where all data sets with one-level names are stored. This library must exist.

Make sure the the file space is "close" to where the processing is done or file transfer will be a bottleneck.